# How to get sharepoint web service?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, android

I am new in sharepoint.
I want to create a user login in android application but i have to use a sharepoint 2013 web service to check the user login authentication.

and also want to know how can i get sharepoint 2013 web service URL?

Answer (score 1):

For Authentication you can use `Authentication.Login` method. This accepts a username and password

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcauthentication.authentication.login.aspx

Detailed web service references is available in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193051.aspx

The webservice URL remains constant and only the web application URL changes.

Ex: `http://weburl/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx` here you can switch `weburl` to the SharePoint server you are trying to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do remote authentication, tutorial available in http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/